# javascript,nodejs. Cannot find module "remarkable"

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, markdown

I want to add a table of contents to my markdown article in webset. When I use [markdown-toc](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/markdown-toc), I found this [issue](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/markdown-toc/issues/165).

The code in my editor is like this：

```
import toc from "markdown-toc";
var toc = require('markdown-toc');
toc('# One\n\n# Two').content;
```

The code is the same as the introduction of [markdown-toc](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/markdown-toc)， but it fails when running on my computer.

After running, it will display like this in the browser console：

```
Error: Cannot find module 'remarkable'
    at webpackEmptyContext (eval at ./node_modules/_markdown-toc@1.2.0@markdown-toc/lib sync recursive (0.js:103), <anonymous>:2:10)
    at Function.getter [as Remarkable] (index.js?937e:34)
    at toc (index.js?c3bd:29)
    at eval (Detail.vue?a2a1:32)
    at Module../node_modules/_cache-loader@4.1.0@cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/_babel-loader@8.1.0@babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/_cache-loader@4.1.0@cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/_vue-loader@15.9.3@vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/views/Detail.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (0.js:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (Detail.vue?13db:1)
    at Module../src/views/Detail.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (0.js:198)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
```

The error is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJNsX.png).

I feel it's a problem from the npm package of markdown-toc. I feel the packages didn't correctly import by the package of "lazy-cache".

The following codes are copied from [the utils file](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/markdown-toc/blob/master/lib/utils.js) .

```
require('concat-stream', 'concat');
require('gray-matter', 'matter');
require('list-item', 'li');
require('markdown-link', 'mdlink');
require('minimist');
require('mixin-deep', 'merge');
require('object.pick', 'pick');
require('remarkable', 'Remarkable');
require('repeat-string', 'repeat');
require('strip-color');
```

If you have such a problem and know how to solve it, I hope you can tell me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, this is the first time to ask a question on this platform, please take care of it. I posted the error picture to the second picture link, hoping to get help.

Comment: Please provide some more details.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of the error. Post actual error here. @longwayya

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have reorganized my language and hope to express it clearly.